# Unable to save string data containing modulo in a column

Tags: c#, sql, json

I have a table with a column of type varchar, and I am serializing an object to json and trying to save it in the column.

The serialized json object:

```
{  
   "query":"select * from tablename where timestamp like concat(nvarchar,convert(date,getdate()),120,'%')"
}
```

When I am saving the above data in a varchar column it gives below error.

"The datatype varchar and varchar are incompatible in the modulo operator"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should escape your quotes with `\'`

Comment: change '%' with ''%'' here '' is double single quote ' ' note double quote.

Comment: @BhubanShrestha It gives error "String or binary data would be truncated."

Comment: your varchar column has less character support than your query string length. Update varchar(size) to varchar(higher_size)

Comment: @BhubanShrestha I don't think so because I have already saved much larger values. It has something to do with the modulo operator i am sure.

Comment: Error message directly means your column has permitted less character than that of your supplied values. What value you have set for varchar field.

Comment: @BhubanShrestha Changing '%' to ''%'' worked,Sorry  I didn't read your comment properly and used double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use escape character with `%` symbol. It should be ''%'' in your string. Complete string should be like following:

```
{"query":"select * from tablename where timestamp like concat(nvarchar,convert(date,getdate()),120,''%'')"}.
```

If you are passing serialized JSON object as parameter then use `QUOTENAME()` function like this.

```
QUOTENAME(@parameterforserializedjsonobject, '''')
```